# Getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: describe when trying to run tests with mocha and phantom js

Tags: requirejs, phantomjs, mocha.js, durandal

I'm having problems testing my durandal application with mocha using phantomJs. Here is what I did:

Firt I created a dummyPage to include the tests with the requireJs environment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mocha.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chai.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mocha.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/require/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require.config({
            baseUrl: '../app/',
            paths: {
                'app': '../app',
                'specs': '../sampleTest/specs/',
                'text': '../lib/require/text',
                'durandal': '../lib/durandal/js',
                'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
                'transitions' : '/lib/durandal/js/transitions',
                'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0',
                'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1'
            }
        });
        var runTests = function (specfiles) {
            console.log('enter runTests');
            require(specfiles, function () {
                mocha.setup('bdd');
                assert = chai.assert;

                mocha.run();
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My dummyTest looks like that:

console.log('enter dummy test');

```
define(['viewmodels/flickr'], function (flickr) {
    describe('Test 1', function(){
        it('should append a value', function () {
            var arr = [];
            arr.push('foo');
            arr.push('bar');
            assert.equal(arr[0],'foo', 'foo is a string');
        });
    });
})
```

When I run phantomJs with the following js-file I'm getting the error:

> Getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: describe

```
page.onLoadFinished = function () {
    page.evaluate(function (specFiles) {
        runTests(specFiles);
    }, specFiles);
};

page.open('mocha.htm');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me the problem is that Mocha is not correctly initialized before you start requiring the modules that contain your tests. Change your `runTests` function so that the initialization your test modules need is performed *before* they are loaded. like this:

```
var runTests = function (specfiles) {
    console.log('enter runTests');

    // Initialize mocha and leak assert into the global space.
    mocha.setup('bdd');
    assert = chai.assert;

    require(specfiles, function () {
        mocha.run();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you that resolves the problem. Do you also know how to display the result of the test when I run "phantomjs spec.js". Currently I can not see any output

Comment: I use Mocha, Chai and RequireJS, and this was enough to answer your question here but I don't use PhantomJS so I can't help regarding this new problem. I would suggest checking the PhantomJS questions already on SO to make sure it's not been answered yet and if it's not been answered then asking a new question.